# PowerScript Filtering Paradox

Tags: powershell, active-directory, where-object

Some records have account type N and others have account type G in this example.

Why does the filter work in this script:

```
Get-Content "MembersMS.txt" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties name, uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType} | Where-Object {($_['uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType'] -ne "N")}
```

i.e., you get only the G records, but not this one:

```
Get-Content "MembersMS.txt" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties * | select name, uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType} | Where-Object {($_['uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType'] -ne "N")}
```

i.e., you get both the N and G records.

The extra "pipe" in the second script allows for a much nicer format since you get much less data per record; you get columnar output, one row per record.

I have tried -notlike "*N*" to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the properties or filtering but with the position of the  `Select` statement, and how it changes the following statements in the pipeline.

The first statement:

```
Get-Content "MembersMS.txt" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties name, uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType} | Where-Object {($_['uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType'] -ne "N")}
```

Can be broken up into 2 statements:

```
$AllUsers = $Get-Content "MembersMS.txt" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties name, uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType}

$AllUsers | Where-Object {($_['uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType'] -ne "N")}
```

Similarly, the second statement:

```
Get-Content "MembersMS.txt" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties * | select name, uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType} | Where-Object {($_['uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType'] -ne "N")}
```

Can be broken up into 2 statements:

```
$AllUsers2 = Get-Content "MembersMS.txt" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties * | select name, uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType} 

$AllUsers2 | Where-Object {($_['uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType'] -ne "N")}
```

Both statements generate arrays:

```
PS C:\> $AllUsers.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array

PS C:\> $AllUsers2.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

But the objects *inside* the array are different.

```
PS C:\> $AllUsers[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    ADUser                                   Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount

PS C:\> $AllUsers2[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    ADUser                                   System.Object
```

The first is an array of Type `ADAccount` and the second is an array of `Sytem.Object` accounts. This is ok if you are iterating over (and filtering over) the items inside the *array*. But this is different when you are iterating/filtering over properties *inside* the array.

The way you use `Where-Object` tries to invoke the `GetEnumerator()` Method, which the Type `ADAccount` conveniently has, but `System.Object` does not.

```
PS C:\> $AllUsers | Get-Member

   TypeName: Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser

Name                   MemberType            Definition
----                   ----------            ----------
GetEnumerator          Method                System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()
Name                   Property              System.String Name {get;}
...

PS C:\> $AllUsers2 | Get-Member

   TypeName: Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Name        NoteProperty string name=HAL9256
```

Therefore it can't enumerate over the properties and properly perform the `Where-Object` filtering.

The better method is to do the "formatting" of `Select` at the end of the pipeline:

```
Get-Content "MembersMS.txt" | ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Identity $_ -Properties name, uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType} | Where-Object {($_['uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType'] -ne "N")} } | Select name, uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain why this happens we need to look at [`ADPropertyCollection` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adpropertycollection?view=activedirectory-management-10.0), this class, similar to [`PropertyValueCollection` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.propertycollection.item?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-directoryservices-propertycollection-item(system-string)), have a [`Item[String]` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adpropertycollection.item?view=activedirectory-management-10.0#microsoft-activedirectory-management-adpropertycollection-item(system-string)) which, basically allows getting a property value by index, i.e.:

```bash
(Get-ADUser krbtgt)['samAccountName']
```

Would work fine to get the `samAccountName` of `krbtgt`.

However, if we attempt to use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2) to filter some of the object's properties, the object would no longer be of the same type ([`ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.aduser?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) in this case), it would be a [`PSObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#outputs) and `PSObject`'s don't have an `Item[String]` parameterized property:

```bash
# no longer works
(Get-ADUser krbtgt | Select-Object samAccountName)['samAccountName']
```

So ideally, you should use `Select-Object` as the last statement of your pipeline. Do note, `Get-ADUser` already supports piping identities so `ForEach-Object` is not needed:

```bash
Get-Content "MembersMS.txt" | Get-ADUser -Properties uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType |
    Where-Object { $_['uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType'] -ne "N" } |
    Select-Object name, uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType
```

It's also worth noting that, if you where using dot notation instead of indexing, both code snippets would've worked:

```bash
Where-Object { $_.'uht-IdentityManagement-AccountType' -ne "N" }
```